# Karma-coverage how to set colouration options and ignore options

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

We're using karma-runner with coverage. The report automatically colours the report green, yellow, and red based on some defaults. I want to set custom thresholds.

Also, I want to use some Istanbul-like flags to get Coverage to ignore certain functions that are not testable (namely functions with angularjs directives).

The coverage report has a footnote saying it was generated with Istanbul, but Istanbul's options and flags aren't working. I can't find anything relevant in Karma's, Karma-runner's, or Karma-coverage's docs.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really old but I found myself looking for the answer and the configuration of Karma doesn't seem to have changed that much. This is perfectly valid for a modern Angular (e.g. 15) project.

As of today the answer is in [this section](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage/blob/HEAD/docs/configuration.md#watermarks) of the **karma-coverage** documentation, which is the module that deals with the console reporting.

```
coverageReporter: {
  watermarks: {
    statements: [ 50, 75 ],
    functions: [ 50, 75 ],
    branches: [ 50, 75 ],
    lines: [ 50, 75 ]
  }
}
```

> The first number is the threshold between Red and Yellow. The second number is the threshold between Yellow and Green.

I hope this helps someone else.